# Using QThreads to execute QWidget::grab() during QDialog::exec()

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qdialog

I have written a Qt program where a series of plots are generated when the user uploads a certain data file and hits a push button. When the push button is pressed, the program will compute a series of calculations and plot a handful of graphs and show them on the screen on the function call `QDialog::exec()`. What I am trying to achieve is to `grab` the screen-shots of the generated plots using `QWidget::grab()`. So essentially the `QWidget::grab()` is called right after `QDialog::exec()`. But since `QDialog::exec()` keeps running till the particular window is closed by the user, calling `QWidget::grab()` after closing the window does not yield desired results.

This is part of my code;

In `mainwindow.cpp`

```
    graphWindow.setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
    graphWindow.exec(); 
    graphWindow.savePlots();
```

In `graphWindow.savePlots()`

```
void GraphWindow::savePlots()
{ 

  QStringList plotNames;
  plotNames << "Income Statement (Plot A)" << "Income Statement (Plot B)" << "Balance Sheet (Plot A)"
            << "Balance Sheet (Plot B)" << "Cash Flow Plot" << "Holistic Stock Performance";

  for(int item = 0; item < ui->graphTab->count(); item++)
  {
      ui->graphTab->setCurrentIndex(item);
      QWidget * currentWidget = ui->graphTab->widget(item);

      int height = currentWidget->height();
      int width = currentWidget->width();
      int x = currentWidget->x();
      int y = currentWidget->y();

      QRect grabRect(x,y,width,height);

      //destImagePath is a global variable
      QString imageFilePath = destImagePath;
      imageFilePath.append(plotNames.at(item));
      imageFilePath.append(".png");

      currentWidget->grab(grabRect).save(imageFilePath);
  }

     //Reset to first tab after grab
     ui->graphTab->setCurrentIndex(0);
 }
```

I was thinking of bypassing `QDialog::exec()` by running another `QThread` which executes the `GraphWindow::savePlots()` while the window is still running so that screen grabs produce desired results.

Is there any better way to do this? I think creating a new `QThread` just to call one function is very inefficient. Even if it is not, could you please explain how this could be implemented in concurrent `QThreads`.

Comment: That is wrong to call widget methods from worker thread: may or may not work as long as GUI designed to behave on UI thread. You should just call `savePlots()`  from with the dialog executed. Just do it before the dialog quits.

Comment: does it mean call it in the constructor? (I know it won't work since there is nothing to grab when the object is first created) How do I call the `saveplots()` from the dialog? I know what you mean but not so confident in how to implement it. It would be really helpful if you can elaborate pls?

Comment: Why from constructor? When the picture supposed to be ready? You should know. We cannot see that.

Comment: Oh I thought the image should already show in the window for `grab()` to work. Thats the reason I called `exec()` before `saveplots()`. I will try what you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, using a QThread or using QtConcurrent::run is actually not necessary, you can instead queue a call to a slot on the main thread using

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, &graphWindow, &GraphWindow::savePlots);
graphWindow.exec();
```

The advantage in your case, it that it will run on the main thread, so you don't have to bother about threads, synchronization, and all the like for the capture (even though Qt makes it easier).

The only limitation of this approach is that is will effectively "freeze" your application for the duration of the capture. This should normally be quite acceptable considering it would significantly less than a second.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much. I made a small adjustment to your code (added in the EDIT).